# Sitecore Horizon error: Failed to render a page. Error message is logged

Tags: horizon

After installation of Sitecore Horizon when I hit the Horizon URL in the browser, it's throwing me an error:
[image]

I have checked the Horizon log file in the Horizon directory in IIS and the error log is:

```
[ERR] (Sitecore Authoring Host/EC2AMAZ-9FC5VOM) [Sitecore.FederatedUI.PageComposer] Failed to render a fragment "Horizon.App" in region "Shell.Main", with error: "Failed to start rendering"
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacketAsync(Stream transport, AsyncProtocolRequest request)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Sitecore.FederatedUI.PageComposer.Loader.HttpFragmentRenderer.RenderFragment(ServerRendering serverRendering, ExtensionContext extensionContext, RequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue, performed the below steps::

1. Go to the Sitecore instance and open `Sitecore.Horizon.Integration.config` file
   `{root directory}\ sc102xmcm.local\ App_Config\Modules\Horizon\Sitecore.Horizon.Integration.config`
2. Search setting name Horizon.ClientHost

```
<setting name="Horizon.ClientHost" value="https:// horizon.sc102xmcm.local" />
```

It's pointing to the old URL, now update it with the new URL:

```
<setting name="Horizon.ClientHost" value="https:// horizon.abc.com" />
```

3. Go to the Sitecore Horizon instance and open `Host.xml` file
   `{root directory}\ horizon.sc102xmcm.local \Config\Host.xml`
4. Search `<HostBaseUrl>`

```
<HostBaseUrl> https:// horizon.sc102xmcm.local" /></HostBaseUrl>
```

Again, it's pointing to the old URL, now update it with the new URL:

```
<HostBaseUrl> https:// horizon.abc.com</HostBaseUrl>
```